# JavaScript graph are not visible in android webview

Tags: java, javascript, android

i want to call this [graph](http://mediasense2.appspot.com/) in my android web view  but i am unable to see it . The random below the graph i can see in webview but cant see the graph . i am taking help from [here](http://benaskins.github.com/simplegraph/)
Thanks

Comment: @CD Sanchez  if u mean to say android browser then no its not working . On the web its working well

Comment: @user667340: Unfortunately, if it doesn't work in the browser it's unlikely that you'll get it working in a WebView. It's probably incompatible with some component (webkit, JS engine) that the browser and WebView both use.

Comment: Any idea to have same type of easy graphs which are compact-able with android

Comment: @user667340: I believe [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) (requires jQuery) works well on Android. I'm sure there several other libraries that are compatible as well.

Comment: @ CD Sanchez Thanks i will give a try to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This utilizes SVG, which is not supported on Android.

---

Let me clarify that, btw.  Adroid has some support for SVG in Honeycomb.  If you're testing on a Galaxy or other pre-honeycomb device, you're out of luck.